# Socket.io connection connecting many times, I think it should be just once

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have built a webapp, based on wes bos's course: 
https://github.com/wesbos/Learn-Node/tree/master/stepped-solutions/45%20-%20Finished%20App

Now, I want to add a simple messaging system, so I'm trying to add socket.io

On their website: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ they suggest this code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

So in my start.js file I'm trying to adapt it to the code above, and it partly works, only that on their website it says it should only log once for every connected user.

And in my case it logs like every frame.

Any idea what is wrong?

This is my start.js

```
const app = require('./app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});

// const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

EDIT:  Here is also my ap.js:

```
// create our Express app
const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); // this is the folder where we keep our pug files
app.set('view engine', 'pug'); // we use the engine pug, mustache or EJS work great too

// serves up static files from the public folder. Anything in public/ will just be served up as the file it is
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Takes the raw requests and turns them into usable properties on req.body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Exposes a bunch of methods for validating data. Used heavily on userController.validateRegister
app.use(expressValidator());

// populates req.cookies with any cookies that came along with the request
app.use(cookieParser());

// Sessions allow us to store data on visitors from request to request
// This keeps users logged in and allows us to send flash messages
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

// // Passport JS is what we use to handle our logins
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// // The flash middleware let's us use req.flash('error', 'Shit!'), which will then pass that message to the next page the user requests
app.use(flash());

// pass variables to our templates + all requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.h = helpers;
  res.locals.flashes = req.flash();
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.currentPath = req.path;
  next();
});

// promisify some callback based APIs
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.login = promisify(req.login, req);
  next();
});

// After allllll that above middleware, we finally handle our own routes!
app.use('/', routes);

// If that above routes didnt work, we 404 them and forward to error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.notFound);

// One of our error handlers will see if these errors are just validation errors
app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);

// Otherwise this was a really bad error we didn't expect! Shoot eh
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  /* Development Error Handler - Prints stack trace */
  app.use(errorHandlers.developmentErrors);
}

// production error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.productionErrors);

// done! we export it so we can start the site in start.js
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: How are you testing it or what is the client application that is connecting to cause multiple connected sockets?

Comment: I can see lots of logs on the chrome console,  but im not doing nothing special so that there would be many sockets... im thinking somehow a function is being called over and over but dont know where.

Comment: Is the top code snippet your app.js file? If not, what is app.js doing?

Comment: app js is actually doing a lot... i have updated the post so you can see app.js thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the following line:

```
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

You're listening here, but you should be doing this:

```
const http = require('http').Server(app);
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

or with your case of setting the port through express:

```
const http = require('http').Server(app);
http.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

A more common syntax is to declare you port as a const:

```
const PORT = 7777
const http = require('http').Server(app);
http.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

In turn, your socket.io server will be created as:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

As it stands your are (from what I can tell) creating two servers.

EDIT:

Your entire start.js should look like this:

```
const app = require('./app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);

const http = require('http').Server(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(http)

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('as user connected' + Math.random());
});

http.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: That did not work... I still get one log per frame... When I should get one. I'll post my new code. Thx

Comment: To clarify, you are only calling listen once now?

Comment: Listen should only be called once with socket.io used this way. Anything else is the client. If you are refreshing or something and getting a new connection, that is how it is supposed to work

Comment: im listening onece on the server and once on socket.io, you can see the updated code... on the client im only loading the socket.io library once, at the end of my layout template, and calling io()

Comment: You're still calling it twice. I'll update my answer to be more clear

Comment: I've updated it. Basically on `const io = require('socket.io')(http)` you are still calling `listen`. The entire server object only needs to be told to listen once.